# Nokogiri won't load in script

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using Ruby for the first time and have to process XML files. Nokogiri appears to be the best way to accomplish this, but I am doing something wrong.  When I load in IRb things work great:

```
$ irb
2.1.0 :001 > require 'nokogiri'
 => true
2.1.0 :002 > exit
```

but when I attempt the same thing from a script I get an error:

```
$ ./sample.rb
./sample.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- nokogiri (LoadError)
    from ./sample.rb:3

$ cat sample.rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'nokogiri'
```

What is different in the script environment that prevents loading?

Comment: Are you using something like RVM? What’s the result of running `which ruby`?

Comment: Add the output of `gem env` to your question, formatted for readability. Are you using RVM or rbenv? Do you have a separate Ruby loaded beyond the one in `/usr/bin/ruby`? We have to guess at this point because you haven't told us enough to help.

Comment: Tim Man - this has already been solved.  GDP2 had the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` instead of `#!/usr/bin/ruby` since IRB might be using a different Ruby than the one located at `/usr/bin/ruby`.

Comment: Brilliant!  I didn't think it would be so easy.  Thanks.

Comment: @wesmat Sure thing. If you want to know more about why `#!/usr/bin/env <argument>` is better than just a path, you should take a look at this answer on the Unix stack exchange: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12751/119644

Comment: This is going to be useful beyond the ruby project.  A simple way to let scripts adapt to the current user env.  Very nice. Again, thanks.

Comment: This worked great for irb - but now I am attempting to get ruby working in as a script in apache.  The same problem appears to be the issue. Is there a tweak to getting the env correct in apache?  The apache log show this:

Comment: The apache log show this:

[Tue Jan 05 15:20:52 2016] [error]  /usr/bin/env:
[Tue Jan 05 15:20:52 2016] [error]  ruby
[Tue Jan 05 15:20:52 2016] [error]  : No such file or directory
[Tue Jan 05 15:20:52 2016] [error] 
[Tue Jan 05 15:20:52 2016] [error]  Premature end of script headers: hello.rb